# Passing env variables from one service to another inside docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to pass environment variables from one service to the other inside docker-compose.yml ?

```
services:
 testService:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: 1234
 testServiceTests:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: I want to pull in the value 1234 here from service1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

However, there's an alternative. You may provide environment variables to all the services within the Docker Compose file by exposing them either from your shell, when you run the Compose or by using a special `.env` file, See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Using this approach, you would have a global (for the Compose) environment variable, say `GLOBAL_TEST_KEY` (it needn't have a different name) and you would be able to *share* this across multiple services:

```
services:
 testService:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: ${GLOBAL_TEST_KEY}
 testServiceTests:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: ${GLOBAL_TEST_KEY}
```

And then: `docker-compose run -e GLOBAL_TEST_KEY="Some value" ....`

Or, create a file called `.env` alongside `docker-compose.yaml` and, in `.env`:

```
GLOBAL_TEST_KEY="Some value"
```

And then: `docker-compose run ...`

> **NOTE** No need to reference `.env` as it's included by default

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible and I'm surprised no one posted it here

```yaml
services:
 testService:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: &myref 1234
 testServiceTests:
    environment:
      TEST_KEY: *myref
```

You can also do

```yaml
services:
 testService:
    environment: &myObj
      TEST_KEY: 1234
      ANOTHER_KEY: 5678
 testServiceTests:
    environment:
        <<: *myObj # import all vars from testService
        THIRD_KEY: abcd # only available for testServiceTests
```

These are called YAML anchors and aliases.